# Weighting the flow accumulation raster by the slope raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, slope, flow-accumulation, weighted

I am trying to represent de equation of Mahoney et al. (2018)
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022169418302877

[image]

Where *Si* is the slope in the cell *i*, *ΣSup* is is the sum of the slopes of each cell upstream of cell *i* and *N* is representative of the number of upstream cells flowing into cell *i*, determined via the Flow Accumulation tool. They say that this is determined by weighting the flow accumulation raster by the slope raster, but I don't localize the way to solve with a raster that represent the sum of the upstream slopes.

Is this possible or it is necesary more steps to solve?

Comment: In ArcGis and TauDEM dialogs of flow accumulation has optional WEIGHT raster.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution through SAGA independently of Qgis, using the function "Catchment area (parallel)" or "Flow accumulation (top-down)".

This is achieved by inserting the filled DEM as 'elevation' and the slope raster layer as 'Accumulated material'